# How to pay electric bill in Thailand

Tags: thailand, payment, utilities

I got my first electric bill

[image]

I am used to get bank account number I need to pay into with my bill. I then usually can go and pay online, however I couldn't find any bank numbers on the slip...

**How does one pay electric bill in Thailand?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I apologize for an extended quotation, but there's really little to add to what [this article](http://www.tielandtothailand.com/how-to-pay-thai-electric-bill/) says. I've just highlighted the most outstanding details:

> By far the easiest way to pay an electric bill in Thailand is to go to your local **7-Eleven or Tesco Lotus Express**, which can be found on practically every town block.
> Make sure to bring the **original bill** with you and go to any register.
> The cashier will scan it and ring it up separately from any other purchases you may have.
> There will be a small **convenience fee** added to the bill (we’re talking only a few baht) and then the cashier will **staple a receipt** to the original bill for you to keep after you’ve paid it.

---

> Alternatively, you can pay the electric company directly at one of their offices.

You may find PEA [office locations](https://www.pea.co.th/en/) in your area

[image: PEA office]

> …which are easily recognized by the buildings’ white and purple exterior.
>
> If you pay here, there’s a good chance that there will be a bit longer wait than if you were to pay at your local 7-Eleven or Tesco Lotus Express. It’s simply because these offices handle more than just monthly payments. On the plus side, you won’t be charged a convenience fee.
>
> When you first walk inside one of the PEA offices, you should spot either a **number-generating kiosk** or a little table or podium with paper slips in numerical order. Grab a number and take a seat. Big offices are usually equipped with an announcing system and number **display board** (similar to the DMV), so all you have to do is wait for your number and respective counter number to be called.
>
> Bring with you your original bill and the cash to the counter. You won’t have to say a word to the cashier. Just pass everything over and in less than a minute the cashier will return the bill along with a **payment receipt** and any change.

---

Also, make sure your payment doesn't go overdue. From the same article:

> You’ll have **ten days to pay** your PEA electric bill after it’s been issued. The payment period (not just a single date) is listed at the bottom right hand corner of the receipt in the format:

```
DD-DD  MM YYYY     or    DD MM-DD MM YYYY
```

In your sample bill, **08 ก.พ. 2560** stands for **08/Feb/2017**.

Answer (score 2):

I have my electric bills automatically withdrawn by MEA (Metropolitan Electricity Agency) from my bank account at Bangkok Bank. This has the advantage that I can never forget to pay my MEA bills, even while I am out if the country.

While this is common in my country (Germany), here in Thailand only authorities may do that. And install it is quite complicated: you have to go to MEA and tell them that you want to have the money withdrwan from your bank account (ผม/ฉันอยากให้ MEA หักเงินราคาไฟจากบัญชีของผมครับ/ฉันค่ะ). They will give a paper document which you have to have sighed by your bank and then bring it back to MEA.

I do live in Northaburi which is Covered by MEA. I do not know whether other electricity suppliers in other cities do money withdrawal too.