# How does one pay electricity bill in advance to avoid turn-off?

Tags: thailand

I rent condo in Bangkok and pay electricity bills at the 7-11. I will be out of country for about 3 months and have been advised not to turn off service while I'm gone.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you have several options:

1. Contact your landlord and ask them to pay the bills while you're absent. You probably meet them anyway because you'll be paying the rent in advance, correct?
2. Find PEA [office location](https://www.pea.co.th/en/) in your area and negotiate this with them (more instructions [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/10160/70)). I believe you are not the first one who temporarily leaves the country, and PEA knows how to handle this;
3. Just delegate this to your friend or neighbor you trust to. A friend who visits your place once a week is also a good security measure, too.

Comment: Thank you so much. One other option, can I pay more than my current amount due at 7-11 (as I will receive receipt) if I cannot make it to PEA?

Comment: @Caroline, in theory, you can. Anecdotally, once I've lost a receipt stapled with the electricity bill, and my girlfriend went to 7-11 and paid it again thinking it wasn't paid yet. I didn't raise any dispute for it's only a couple hundred Baht, waited till the next month and, lo and behold, my next bill had an extra line "overpay nnn Baht" or so, with almost zero total due. Still, I suggest doing this in PEA office, however, to avoid any unpleasant surprises.